# MVC DropDownListFor basic True False in View Text Change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Supervisior, new { @class = "" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Supervisior, new { @class = "", required = "required", form_id="form1" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Supervisior)
</div>
```

Property `Supervisor` is a nullable bool

```
public Nullable<bool> Supervisior { get; set; }
```

I want the display names of the dropdownlist generated by `EditorFor()` to be, for `true`, display "Confirm", and for `false`, display "Reject".

Comment: Unclear what you asking. What is property `Supervisior` - a `bool`? (and you need to remove `required = "required"` - that is HTML5 validation, and `@class = ""` is a bit pointless)

Comment: At the moment the database automatically comes up with a true false query to the list . Dropdown List has been 1. True 2. False item So ı want text change displayed name Sample True displayed : ABC False displayed : HGF on list. just ı want displayed name change on dropdown list for TRUE and FALSE

Comment: Again, what is `typeof` property `Supervisior` (and edit your question with the relevant details)

Comment: http://prnt.sc/dz1w7x check my print screen

Comment: You need to edit your question! (which I have now done for you). And what do you want the display name to be for a `null` value?

Comment: Yes ı see you can do edit my question thanks. so if it null = displayed name : Select

Comment: That does not make sense (you don't even have a `[Required]` attribute, therefore you property should not be `nullable`. And you property name does not make sense (is should be something like `bool IsSupervisor` is you want to indicate if the object is a Supervisor or not (but then that conflicts with the terms "Confirm" and "Reject" so its not clear what you need. But you would need to create a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in the controller and use the `DropDownListFor()` method

Comment: I am not sure I understood what they said but I didn't do it before ı can't do similiar method  . so ı need practice for it and searching how can add IEnumerable on controller actually ı want just default data text change.

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Supervisior, new List<SelectListItem>(){ new SelectListItem(){ Value = "True", Text = "Confirm" }, new SelectListItem(){ Value = "False", Text = "Reject" }}, "Please select")`

Comment: I can do thanks good work...